# Unable to locate message source for category ''

Tags: localization, craft3

I'm trying to update my plugin to Craft 3 and I'm getting this error message:

```
Unable to locate message source for category ''.
```

What does it mean?!

Answer (score 5):

In Craft 2, the Craft default Yii translation method was overridden to only require one value, the value of the translatable string:

```
Craft::t('My Translatable String');
```

In Craft 3, Craft reverts to using the [default Yii behavior](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-baseyii.html#t()-detail) for the Translate method `t()` and there are two arguments needed.  The first argument is now the `category` and the second is the translatable string:

```
Craft::t('pluginhandle', 'My Translatable String');
```

Adding the category back allows translations from different contexts to avoid conflicts with each other.

Craft uses the `app` category.  Yii uses the `yii` category.  And plugins should use their own plugin handles.

The front-end of a site should use `site` category, and the actual translation files should be saved in `translations/locale/category.php` (whether that's in `craft/` or `craft/plugins/mypluginname/`)

*(Hat tip to Brandon Kelly for helping me understand this better on Craft Slack)*